# Can $\sum_{i=0}^{n} {i \choose k}$ be simplified such that a general calculator can compute its result?

Tags: combinatorics

Is there any way to simplify $\sum_{i=0}^{n} {i \choose k}$ in such a way that it is computable on a standard calculator similar to how $\sum_{i=0}^{n} {n \choose i} = 2^n$. I can only seem to find answers relating to the latter equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly.  In fact:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{i}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}.
$$
Why? The right side counts the number of ways to choose $k+1$ numbers out of $\{1,2,\ldots,n+1\}$.  The $i$th summand on the left counts the number of ways to choose $k+1$ numbers out of $\{1,2,\ldots,n+1\}$ things such that the highest element chosen is $i+1$ (because you then must choose $k$ more elements out of the $i$ elements smaller than $i+1$).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is well-known that
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{i}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}
$$
by classifying $k+1$ element subsets of $\{0, \dotsc, n\}$ based on their largest element.